# Unexpected token alert from eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js, eslint, quasar-framework, quasar, typescript-eslint

In my Vue 3 Quasar project I have the following component that whenever a change happens it executes a function that receives a number. First I was getting the following error

> Parameter 'n' implicitly has an 'any' type."

```html
<MyComponent
  v-model:current="currentValue"
  :max="someValue"
  @in="myFunction(someNumber)"
  @out="myFunction(someValue)"
  @change="(e) => myFunction(e)"
/>
```

After inferring it's type now I am getting:

> [vue/no-parsing-error]
> Parsing error: Unexpected token :.eslint-plugin-vue

```html
<MyComponent
  v-model:current="currentValue"
  :max="someValue"
  @in="myFunction(someNumber)"
  @out="myFunction(someValue)"
  @change="(e: number) => myFunction(e)"
/>
```

How do I fix or disable this? I assume it  might be an eslint configuration problem and I would prefer to understand this better instead of simply ignore it.

Here's my .eslintrc.cjs

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    parser: require.resolve("@typescript-eslint/parser"),
    extraFileExtensions: [".vue"],
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
    "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true,
  },

  extends: [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "prettier",
  ],

  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "vue"],

  globals: {
    ga: "readonly",
    cordova: "readonly",
    __statics: "readonly",
    __QUASAR_SSR__: "readonly",
    __QUASAR_SSR_SERVER__: "readonly",
    __QUASAR_SSR_CLIENT__: "readonly",
    __QUASAR_SSR_PWA__: "readonly",
    process: "readonly",
    Capacitor: "readonly",
    chrome: "readonly",
  },

  rules: {
    "prefer-promise-reject-errors": "off",
    quotes: ["warn", "single", { avoidEscape: true }],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
  },
};
```

Comment: Please add your eslint config to the question.  It would also be helpful to point out _exactly_ where the eslint error is originating from in your code

Comment: I updated the question with my config file

Comment: and where is the eslint error occurring?  The red squiggly line should be under something... What precisely is that thing?  If it's anywhere on `@change` line, you could just change that line to `@change="myFunction"`, the passing of the param should be implied.

Comment: under the (n) on changes.
Also your answer worked